# Objects disappear on zoom-out

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Is there any way to prevent [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) objects disappearance on zoom-out?

Look at the following JSFiddle I've just created -- https://jsfiddle.net/t3jkrmn6/. Just scroll a canvas and you'll see what I'm talking about.

```
<div id="canvas-wrapper">
  <canvas id="c" class="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

.canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var line = new fabric.Line([100, 50, 100, 100], {
    stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 1
});
canvas.add(line);

$('#canvas-wrapper').mousewheel(function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 1.1);
  } else {
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() / 1.1);
  }
  console.log(canvas.getZoom());
});
```

I want some of my objects to stay 1 width no matter how much user zoomed-out the canvas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your fiddle the objects disappear because you've set the strokeWidth of your line to 1. At any scaling less than 1, it's width becomes <1 pixel and it is therefore invisible.

If you want the line width to remain constant, you'll need to do something like this:

```
$('#canvas-wrapper').mousewheel(function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 1.1);
    line.setStrokeWidth(1.1 / canvas.getZoom());
  } else {
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() / 1.1);
    line.setStrokeWidth(1.1 / canvas.getZoom());
  }
  console.log(canvas.getZoom());
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whippet71/5tjcdyog/3)

Comment: Unfortunately your solution does not work. Keep zooming and you'll notice that the line will disappear eventually

Comment: Looks like there were certain points when the strokeWidth must have been fractionally < 1. Have updated the code fiddle to set strokeWidth to `1.1 / canvas.getZoom()`